# Why is style ignored in XLSX when using markup?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, xlsx

I am using bold style for part of the text, so it looks like:

```
"<style isBold = 'true'>" + $P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString("report.label.foo") +": "+"</style>"+$F{foo}
```

in jrxml this `textField` looks like:

```
<textField>
<reportElement style="moduleBorderColumnStyle" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="6adbbfa7-e549-4378-903c-04095c2f34c4"/>
<textElement markup="styled"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<style isBold = 'true'>" +
$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}
.getString("report.label.foo")
+": "+"</style>"+$F{foo}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**TextField Markup property - styled**

It works perfect for PDF and HTML. However, I have problems with using same for **XLSX**.

Unfortunately, even after setting directly font size to 14 (I've tried to set it from style before) I am getting font  **11 callibri** (It's default font) for whole label, which is using tag `<style isBold='true'>`.

I've tried the same with `<b> text </b>` and markup = HTML - result did not changed.

**Conclusion: Any styled text in XLSX is insensitive for fonts (sets it to default), how can this be resolved?**

**EDIT:**

I found that the problem is in style which I am applying for this `textField` before, however still problem is just in excel. The `<style>` tag just overwrites it to default font and font size.

Comment: @PetterFriberg yes, I still have a question. I don't use conditional styles here. Problem with font overwriting

Comment: @PetterFriberg and just in XLSX

Comment: I think this is bug, I have been testing some, in xlsx (not in xls) the style attribute is ignored if markup is used with textField, I will see if I can find a work around, but as is, **it's a bug**.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thank you, do you have any ideas how to fix it or do it in other way? I could create 2 different text fields but with locale that gonna be ugly (different margins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm same bug when exporting to `xlsx`, style is ignored, it seems related to creating the `RichTextString` for the cell in the `XSSFSheet`. (incorrect/no font is set to `RichTextString`?)

> **EDIT:** I have created a [bug issue](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/8326), that is marked as solved for next release (current release was v6.3.0)

## Simple example to reproduce bug

**jrxml (SimpleTest.jrxml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SimpleTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="e4188d8a-c7f9-4f7d-8f0f-ada07b89d42f">
    <style name="test" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#CC0000" fontSize="14"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="test" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="6d5644bf-480e-4ed2-831b-3ed043f38f70"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>TEST</b> TEXT"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="test" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="200" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="f876d0a3-136b-468c-b3bd-bd9cd5475ca9"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["TEXT2"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**java code to export to xls and xlsx**

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("SimpleTest.jrxml");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JREmptyDataSource(1));

//Export to excel xls
JRXlsExporter exporterXls = new JRXlsExporter();
File outputFile = new File("excelTest.xls");
exporterXls.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporterXls.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configXls = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configXls.setDetectCellType(true);
configXls.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
configXls.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
configXls.setCollapseRowSpan(true);
configXls.setWhitePageBackground(false);
exporterXls.setConfiguration(configXls);
exporterXls.exportReport();

//Export to excel xlsx
JRXlsxExporter exporterXlsx = new JRXlsxExporter();
File output = new File("excelTest.xlsx");
exporterXlsx.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporterXlsx.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(output));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configXlsx = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
configXlsx.setDetectCellType(true);
configXlsx.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
configXlsx.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
configXlsx.setCollapseRowSpan(true);
configXlsx.setWhitePageBackground(false);
exporterXlsx.setConfiguration(configXlsx);
exporterXlsx.exportReport();
```

**Output xls (left), xlsx (right)**

[image: result]

> cell A1 in xlsx the **style is not applied**

## Work around

Do **not use style** on the `textField`, hence apply the style directly to the `textField`.

In example we add the `forecolor="#CC0000"` and `fontSize="14"` to `textField` and remove the `style` attribute

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" forecolor="#CC0000" uuid="6d5644bf-480e-4ed2-831b-3ed043f38f70"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
        <font size="14"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>TEST</b> TEXT"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: @quento FYI: I have open a bug issue see http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/8326, since I could not find any related issue, the jasper-reports guys are very nice so they will probably step by soon

Comment: Thank you all for spotting on this bug. It was now fixed and the fix will be available with the next JasperReports release.

Comment: @PetterFriberg What if removing style attribute is not an option ?

Comment: @AmmarAkouri get latest release of jasper-report or post elaborate it with poi, I can't see many other solutions.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I'm already having the latest one, my problem is that the colors and text alignments are displayed exactly as I want them to be in the PREVIEW mode, but when I export to Excel the colors seem to get a bit darker, and text alignments are ignored. I tried what you suggested and applied the style directly on the textfield but no luck at all !

Comment: For anyone who's having the same problem as me, I downgraded from Jasper 6.5.1 to 5.0.0, recompiled the jrxml files and everything went good.